# How to split time in a given time range in a dataframe? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame looks like this,

```
 **Date**      **School**     **Number of Students**
1978-03-10      York_HS                258 
1978-03-23      York_HS                106
1978-04-07      York_HS                523  
1978-04-12      York_HS                587 
1978-04-19      York_HS                265
1978-05-01      York_HS                106
1978-05-10      York_HS                201
1978-06-18      York_HS                225
```

I would like to split the time from 1978-03-10 to 1978-06-18 with time interval as 30 days, to count the average student number. For example, 1978-03-10 to 1978-04-08(30 days) as first month and 1978-04-09 to 1978-05-08 as second month and 1978-05-09 to 1978-06-07 as third month.

Is it possible to return the result as a DataFrame like this?

```
    **Date**       **School**      **Average Number of Students**
    1978-04-08      York_HS                 29.56 
    1978-05-08      York_HS                 31.93
    1978-06-07      York_HS                 14.20
```

The code I used below returns a time split started from 1978-03-10, may I know how to return the result in a DataFrame type as I shown above?

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def period(begin, end, delta):
    begin = begin
    while begin < end:
        yield begin
        begin += delta

for result in period(date(2014, 9, 19), date(2016, 12, 23), timedelta(days=30)):
      print (result)
```

Comment: You must change to `begin = begin`, not `begin = start`

Comment: Is this question about pandas?

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes, I used Python pandas.

Comment: @DoNhuVy Thank you so much! I've changed it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `pandas` makes this easy.

Using a toy example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> p = pd.date_range('2012/01/01', '2012/03/01', freq='W')
>>> datum = np.random.randint(100, 300, size=9)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'n_students': datum}, index=p)
>>> df
<<<
            n_students
2012-01-01         138
2012-01-08         293
2012-01-15         166
2012-01-22         105
2012-01-29         151
2012-02-05         167
2012-02-12         265
2012-02-19         113
2012-02-26         110
```

We just do:

```
>>> df.resample('M').mean()
<<<             n_students
    2012-01-31      170.60
    2012-02-29      163.75
```

Which is what you want.

Two things to be aware of:

1. Your dates must be the index of your `DataFrame`. If they are not, you can make them the index using `df.set_index("Date")`.
2. You dates must be of the `datetime64[ns]` type, or something that gets cast to that type (like a `datetime`, which appears to be what you are using).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way to calculate the average daily number of students per month as follows,

```
n_students_month = df.groupby([(df.index.year), (df.index.month)]).sum()/30
```